# Valuing an option when we have a view on future price of underlying

Tags: options, option-pricing, american-options

I have a model that predicts the future price of a stock, and would like to incorporate this information to value the option. Lets take an example. AAPL stock is trading at 151.89 US dollars today (Sep 22, 2017). I would like to compute the fair value of the call option with a strike of 149 that expires on Oct 20, 2017. From the market I can get the current mid price of the option and its implied volatility. However, lets say my model predicts that the value of AAPL on Oct 20, 2017 is normally distributed with a mean of 145 dollars and a standard deviation of 1 dollar. How could I use this information to compute the value of the option? For the purposes of this question, we can assume the dividend yield is 0 and we know the risk free rate.  If somebody has a way to do this for a European option instead of an American that would probably be close enough for my purposes.

The purpose of computing the value is so I can buy or sell the option where market price is most different from the value computed above thus maximizing risk adjusted return. The assumption, of course is that my model is accurate.

Comment: If you have a predicted distribution of the underlying, then the corresponding option price (undiscounted) according to that prediction is just the integral of the payoff and the distribution.

Comment: I think that makes a lot of sense.  Would you discount the option back using a rate derived from the variance of the distribution?

Comment: that depends on your model, but given your question I doubt it.

Comment: How would you discount the undiscounted option value back to today?  Intuitively it seems to me that the bigger the variance of the underlying price prediction is, the less valuable the option would be today since the risk would be higher.

Comment: I think you need to do some reading on the topic. The reality is that options increase in value as you increase the volatility, which makes sense when you think about the integral i mention in my comment. as for discounting it back to today, it is not related to the variance, it is to do with the value of having money now vs. having it in the future. I i can invest £95 now in a product that will pay me £100 in 1 year (i.e. a zero coupon bond), then if the expected value of your option comes out to £20 in one year, then today that is worth £20 * £95/£100 = £19 today.

Comment: OK, I get it.  Misread your initial comment.  Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: How would you compute the integral of a normal distribution and a call option payoff function.  Is there a closed form solution? Any suggestions on where I could read up on this?

Comment: yes there is a closed form. Have you tried even a cursory Internet search?

Comment: Yes I have.  Look, if you don't want to help, or don't know the answer, or are just having a bad day, you don't have to answer.  Being snarky is not helping the conversation.  I could have pointed out that you clearly don't understand the difference between discounting risky and riskless cashflows in your second comment, but I chose to be decent about it.

Comment: it's not that I don't want to help, it's that the things you're asking are very basic. Given that you've made no mention of it, I assumed that you're assuming the discounting is uncorrelated with the underlying, in which case discounting the risky and riskless assets is the same. If you Google "normal vol option price", the top hit has the answer you're looking for on the first page, for both calls and puts. If you didn't know to search "option price" then the formula you need is on the Wikipedia page for "list of gaussian integrals". I'm sorry if you feel hard done by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot incorporate your own prediction into the "fair value" of the option. "Fair value" of the option is the initial amount required to set up the replication hedging portfolio, and is shown to be equal to the discounted expectation of the option payoff under the risk neutral measure, not the subjective measure that comes out of your "personal" model. You can however compute the distribution of return of buying or selling an option under your "personal" model and build your investment strategy accordingly.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, it seems I could value the option just using the predicted distribution of the underlying.  Lets say that the call option is European.  Then on expiry, the distribution of the option price would be the same as the distribution of the underlying - strike, but it would be cut off, i..e probabilities would be 0 when the underlying is less than the strike price.  The value of the option is then the mean of a normal distribution which is cut off on the left?  Does the variance of the distribution matter or does it not matter because of risk neutral pricing?

Comment: Of course in computing an expectation which is "cut off to the left" the variance matters: the higher the variance the higher the expectation.